# R: format string and fill with 0

Tags: r

Is  there a function in R to get the following. Let's  say  i have some inputs like `c("1456-3-13;11:56:98", "45:76:12", "981-56-54;11")`. However, they all should  be in in the form of the regex `"/d{4}-/d{2}-/d{2};/d{2}:/d{2}:/d{2}"`

Whenever a number is missing  in  the  input  it  should be filled  with  zeros  from  left  to  right. So the output of  processing  the  mentioned  inputs should be `c("1456-03-13;11:56:98", "0000-00-00;45:76:12", "0981-56-54;11:00:00").`

Any  idea  how  to do this  in  a clever way  ?:)

Comment: Please provide the sample data using `dput`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit messy, but it seems to work for this case. First I parse the string you have and convert to numeric, then I reformat all the values

```
tests<-c("1456-3-13;11:56:98", "45:76:12", "981-56-54;11", "1456-3-13")

matches<- stringr::str_match(tests, "(?:(\\d+(?=[-;]))(?:-(\\d+)(?:-(\\d+))?)?)?;?(\\d+)?(?::(\\d+)(?::(\\d+))?)?")
matches <- matches[,-1]
class(matches) <- "numeric"
matches[is.na(matches)]<-0

do.call("sprintf", c(list("%04d-%02d-%02d;%02d:%02d:%02d"), lapply(1:ncol(matches), function(i) matches[, i])))

# [1] "1456-03-13;11:56:98" "0000-00-00;45:76:12" "0981-56-54;11:00:00"
# [4] "1456-03-13;00:00:00"
```

Comment: nice solution, However, an example where this seems not to work is for input ""1456-3-13", which should be "1456-3-13;00:00:00" but turns out to be ""0000-00-00;1456:00:00"

Comment: any ideas how to fix this )?

Comment: How would just the number "5" be parsed?

Comment: Yeah good point : D

Comment: I posted an update which handles the additional case you provided, but there may still be others where things fail.